# ширина блока пропорционально высоте

Tags: javascript, css

Есть несколько способов сделать высоту блока пропорционально ширине. А можно ли сделать наоборот: что бы ширина блока была пропорционально высоте? В прикрепленном примере нужно добиться, что бы красный блок оставался квадратом после его растяжения/сжатия

```
.rectangle {
  height: 100%;
  width: ???;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Можно ли этого добиться при помощи `сss`? Или нужно использовать `js`?

```js
var head = window.document.getElementById('head');
var side = window.document.getElementById('side');


window.requestAnimationFrame(function step() {
  var offset = Math.max(0, head.offsetHeight - window.pageYOffset);
  side.style.minHeight = 'calc(100vh - ' + offset + 'px)';
  window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
});


//получаем ширину равную высоте
$(document).ready(function() {
  var w = parseFloat($('.rectangle').css('height'));
  $('.rectangle').css('width', w);
  //получаем ширину при изменении размера окна
  $(window).resize(function() {
var w = parseFloat($('.rectangle').css('height'));
$('.rectangle').css('width', w);
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}


#head {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.aside {
  width: 50%;
}

.main-block {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 2000px;
}

#side {
  position: sticky;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;

}

#side a {
    border-top: 0.1em dashed white;
}

.rectangle {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="head">head</div>
<section class="wrapper">
  <div class="aside">
    <div id="side">
      <a><div class="rectangle"></div></a>
      <a></a>
      <a><div class="rectangle right"></div></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-block"></div>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать применить распорку из прозрачной картинки с соответсвующими пропорциями. В примере ниже использована картинка 16:9. Сами картинки можно сгенерировать, например, [здесь](https://png-pixel.com/).

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 50vh;
}

.box-aspect {
  content: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAJCAQAAACRI2S5AAAAEElEQVR42mNkIAAYRxWAAQAG9gAKqv6+AwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==); 
  height: 100%;
}

.box-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background-color: silver;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-aspect"></div>
  <div class="box-content">Саша Грей готовит пельмени!</div>
</div>
```

А ежели поддержка старых браузеров неважна, то во всех современных, которые поддерживают CSS-переменные, можно делать так:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;

  --height: 50vh;
  width: calc(var(--height) * 1.777); /* 16:9=1.777 */
  height: var(--height);

  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: silver;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Кулинарный канал Саши Грей!
</div>
```

Comment: Оба варианта интересны и работают по отдельности. По при применении их к дочернему элементу в блоке grid - они не работают. Вернее, распорка работает, но поверх нее расположить картинку у меня не получается. при установке свойства absolute элемент позиционируется не по блоку <a></a>, внутри которого находится, а по внешнему блоку.

Comment: Все должно работать, просто вы наверное где-то не учитывете наследование height, либо какой-то нюанс в контексте вашей верстки.